# plotly interpolation between points for missing values in datetime index

Tags: python, plotly, interpolation, missing-data, plotly-python

When using plotly express to graph data with a datetime index, plotly interpolates with linear curves between missing rows (dates). To demonstrate I have made a function to plot the NA values for each row a dataframe:

```py
def notna_plot(df, relative=False):
    # Create a DataFrame with the number of non-null values in each row of the DataFrame.
    if relative == True:
        data = df.notna().sum(axis=1)/len(df.columns)
    else:
        data = df.notna().sum(axis=1)
    fig = px.line(data)
    return fig
```

Which produces the following graph on a certain dataset:
[image: notna_plot of data]

This dataframe is missing the rows for the dates between (Apr 2002, Aug 2003), (May 2009, May 2010), and (Mar 2021, Aug 2021) which on the graph appear as straight lines joining the values on the edges of said ranges.

I would like to gain control over this behaviour to replace the interpolation with a red highligh of the ranges like so:

[image: desired graph]

I have been searching online for a while but have found nothing that works. There was a thread that suggested trying `fig.update_traces(connectgaps=False)` but this produced no changes in the graph. I cannot confirm that this doesn't work, however, because I tried other modifications with .update_traces such as `fig.update_traces(marker={"opacity": 0.4,'color':'Red'},overwrite=True)` per the px documentation, but this would also not produce any changes in the graph.

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The [example](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#highlighting-time-series-regions-with-rectangle-shapes) in the reference shows a line chart of a time series with a rectangle added to highlight a specific date and time. If you use the same technique to specify a rectangle based on your partially missing data, you will get the graph you are looking for.

Comment: @r-beginners I am not looking for help on plotting the boxes but with controlling the intrerpolation between missing dates. If possible I would like to extract these ranges from plotly to remove the connecting line and define the ranges for the red boxes (without doing extra external work with pandas). Is this possible? How can I remove the lines connecting missing values?

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve. Are you saying that the hand-drawn graph boxes are meaningless? I think the simple way to avoid connecting lines is to update the section with no data with NaN and draw a continuous time series with NaN included y-axis values for the x-axis, so that no connecting lines are created.

Comment: @r-beginners My apologies for being unclear, and many thanks for your help by the way. Yes, the boxes are irrelevant to the problem, that is just what I wish the chart to look like in the end. What I am having trouble with is removing the lines that join missing values. I thought of your solution (filling the data with the missing rows) but this is something I need for a platform I am creating to which the user can upload their own data. This means I would have to write an index parser to understand the frequency of the dates in the input data...

Comment: ... which seems more complicated than if there were to be a plotly native solution. The input data could be of daily or weekly frequency. but also monthly (with the dates either being the first day or the last day of the month). This is why I'm looking for a way to modify the plotly behaviour instead of manipulating the data. I have found other posts taking about the rangebreaks argument of fig.update_xaxis() which takes some condition to filter the index but I have no clue how to write the condition for values that do not exist in the df.